# Can the spell Heat Metal target a metallic dragon's scales?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Basically title. Metallic dragons are covered in various types of metallic scales. Can a wizard target the scales to deal ongoing damage to the dragon?

Comment: I added a related question that may get more interesting answers since it gets past the 'manufactured' issue.  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176414/can-the-heat-metal-spell-target-a-set-of-dragon-scale-mail-made-from-metallic-dr

Comment: Worth to note - Some types of Metallic Dragons are fire-typed, and as such wouldn't even be bothered by Heat Metal, if such spell could be applied to their scales in the first place.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### *Heat metal* targets a *manufactured* metal object.

[*Heat metal*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/heat-metal) (PHB, pg. 250) says (emphasis mine):

> Choose a *manufactured* metal object, such as a metal weapon or a suit of heavy or medium metal armor, that you can see within range.

A dragon's scales are not manufactured, rather are entirely natural, so are not eligible to be targeted by *heat metal*.

Comment: On a side note, a dragon's scale wouldn't even be an object while being part of that dragon _"skin"_. It's a body part.

Comment: @KogarashiKaito Maybe, but that falls more into DM-ruling territory than is necessary to sufficiently answer this question.

Comment: OK, but what if it's a dragon-shaped construct that's made out of steel or some such? Then it becomes manufactured!

Comment: @RevenantBacon I thought about this, and my mind wandered to the Chardalyn dragon from *Rime*, but it is made of crystal, not metal.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a Clockwork Dragon, or perhaps an Iron Golem that just happened to be shaped like a dragon.

Comment: Right, but this question is clearly about metallic scaled dragons, not dragon shaped golems.

Answer (score 0):

Metallic dragons have scales that *appear* to be metal but are not actually metal. The scales are organic and as such the spell cannot target the dragon. *Unless* this dragon is actually a construct in which case it can but some DM's might limit the effects of the spell since the construct does not process pain from heat the same way a creature would.

Comment: Do you have a citation for the first sentence?

Comment: Metallic dragons were a type of dragon distinguished typically by the color and composition of their scales, *that was like that of various metals*, hence the name."[link](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Metallic_dragon) not entirely clear but it suggests that they are not in fact metallic

Comment: By citation, I mean a reference to an officially published sourcebook, as anybody can write anything on a wikia page.

Comment: That said, welcome to rpg.se! If you haven't already, take our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). If you have any questions about the site and what we do, take a gander at our [faq index](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/faq-index-for-role-playing-games-stack-exchange) to see if your question is there.

Comment: The closest thing I've found, which isn't really definitive, is from the Monster Manual for gold/copper dragons. "A gold dragon wyrmling has scales of dark yellow with metallic flecks. Those flecks grow larger as the dragon matures" (pg 114) and "At birth, a copper dragon's scales are a ruddy brown with a metallic tint.". For something to have metallic flecks, it can't be composed entirely of that metal, but it does say they grow... And the Copper dragon description supports what I always believed (but can't confirm) - they are just metallic looking rather than actually metal.

Comment: When they refer to construct in the answer, it seems they're talking about a manufactured, mechanical dragon (like Festus, from the Heros of Olympus series)

Comment: In defense of this argument, I will say the emphasis of metallic dragons as being metallic as opposed to metal, seems to imply they are only like metals in luster, rather than composed of metal. However, I wouldn't count this as strong enough evidence to answer the question.

Comment: Heat Metal cannot be used to target Constructs. Spells do what they say they do, and Heat Metal targets Objects, not Creatures, even metallic ones.

Comment: As someone that had to read way too much material about dragons for a previous answer to another question, I'll have to disagree. There is a plethora of material that uses metallic dragon scales as a material for weapons or armor, not only by sewing them together but often by forging them, as if they were metal themselves, into stuff. A DM could easily say that a metallic dragon's scales do in fact contain so much metal that they count as metal for the purpose of metal-related stuff. THAT SAID, this argument is moot - they are not manufactured objects, so the spell can't target them anyway.

Comment: Pyrite is gold-colored. Pyrite has zero gold content. Gold-dragon scales are gold colored. How much gold does this mean they contain?